# How to login to gmail using chrome in windows using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

i am using python script for login to gmail in chrome, but after clicking next the code returning error, can anyone please help me what's wrong, i am new to python. below is the code which i used.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import threading
import os,time,csv,datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
a = webdriver.Chrome()
a.get("https://accounts.google.com/")
user = a.find_element_by_id("Email")
user.send_keys('username@gmail.com')
login = a.find_element_by_id("next")
login.click()
pwd = WebDriverWait(a, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))
pwd.send_keys('p######')
login = a.find_element_by_id("signIn")
login.click()
clk = WebDriverWait(a, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'myaccount')))
clk.click()
logout = WebDriverWait(a, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "gb_71")))
logout.click()
```

Below is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mapraveenkumar\Documents\Python\gmail.py", line 20, in 
    clk = WebDriverWait(a, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'myaccount')))
  File "C:\Users\mapraveenkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Please add the error..

Comment: this is the error: File "C:/Users/mapraveenkumar/Documents/Python/gmail.py", line 12, in <module>
    pwd = a.find_element_by_css_selector("#Passwd")
  File "C:\Users\mapraveenkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 437, in find_element_by_css_selector return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)

Comment: Update the post with error, not here in comments. And the code you have posted and in error doesn't match

Comment: sorry for the error in comments, that is wrong..... i have updated the right one...

Comment: Try adding some sleep time `time.sleep(5)` between clicking `next` and finding `Passwd` input field.

Comment: yeah it worked frank but i am receiving error further when i navigate to logout, i have updated the code with error. Please help me.

Comment: I do not think you have any link with text `myaccount`. By the way, isn't automating Google login a violation of terms?

Comment: I am learning how to login and logout using python with my login. So i think there will no violation. :) But still i am not able to logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's most likely because after clicking on the "Next" button, the page takes some time to load and present the `Password` text field. Try using a [wait statement](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to make sure your script waits until the element can be located.

Example:

```
...
login = a.find_element_by_id("next")
login.click()

pwd = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd"))
pwd.send_keys('password')
...
```

Comment: thanks ralph, it worked well but when i further continued, i received different error, could you please help me with this.  i have edited the code with the error.